# Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) installation fails with error 997: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop on a Windows 7 Pro machine. I've downloaded the ISO file and I'm running that locally.

I run the installer and get an error about certain prerequisites not being installed (the C++ runtimes for one). I've downloaded all the prerequisites, but when I try to install the Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) I get the following error rather unhelpful message:

> Fatal error during installation.

However, checking the log file reveals the following error:

> Package (vs_isoshellcore) failed: Error Message Id: 997 ErrorMessage: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

The [common issues and workarounds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899270) page doesn't seem to mention this issue and a Google search for this message fails to turn up any results.

A search for "Overlapped I/O operation is in progress." brings back more results the most relevant appear to be:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d993437-e737-4611-b6bf-c43f1dc4c00d/vs2013-express-for-web-installation-issue?forum=vssetup

https://community.serif.com/forum/other-products/14966/error-message-overlapped-i-o-operation-in-progress-when-installing-serif-software

and

http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/140586-possible-issue-kb2918614-causing-overlapped-i-o-operation-progress-errors.html

the latter two point to [KB2918614](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2918614) being the culprit. However, removing this update and restarting the machine hasn't fixed the problem.

I've tried running the installer both as a regular user and as an administrator and get the same result.

I've also tried running the web installer and while that seems to do a better job of finding and installing the prerequisites and dependencies it also fails with the same error.

I tried turning my Anti-Virus off in case that was interfering with the installer, but it failed with exactly the same error.

What else can I do?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Lightforce - True - but it's about the installation of programming tools which are on topic. Do you really think I'd post an off topic question?

Comment: No, it's just that I think you may get better support at a microsoft forum. No offence.

Comment: @Lightforce - I found questions on there already - indeed I linked to one - but I found the answers unhelpful - "reinstall Windows 7".

Comment: I see :-) In my opinion the problem is that even after uninstalling KB2918614 you cannot be sure that there aren't any left-overs. Is it possible to install VS when booting in safe mode?

Comment: @Lightforce - it doesn't look like it's possible to install *anything* in safe mode - unless I got that wrong as well.

Comment: @ChrisF, did you end up resolving this problem? I'm struggling with it too.

Comment: @MatthewKing - nope. I've come to the conclusion that I'm going to have to reinstall the OS. The question is do I reinstall 7, go for 8 or wait for 10? Then there's finding an uninterrupted day to do it.

Comment: @ChrisF - Alright, thanks. Looks like that is what I'll be doing, too :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when installing the .NET Framework update v4.5.2. I also tried the same means that you've described (uninstalling, repairing and attempting to re-install the .NET Framework).

Here's what worked for me - note that this *is* a work-around, but nothing else would work:

- I left the KB2918614 installed via the Windows Update process (I had previously uninstalled, and hidden it from updates - I unhid it, then let it install again). This hotfix [has known problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-i-o-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service.aspx) that cause the **997 ErrorMessage: Overlapped I/O operation** error.
- [Request and install](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000988) the hotfix KB3000988 that supposedly fixes the problems caused by KB2918614.
- Perform registry modifications as noted in [KB2918614](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2918614):

  1. Under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`, create DWORD [`NoUACforHashMissing`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3008627), and set value to `1`. (Create the key if it doesn't exist).
  2. Also under the same key, add DWORD `SecureRepairPolicy`, and set value to `2`.

[image: Registry screen-dump]

3. Create a whitelist for apps that are trusted (including future updates) to be digitally signed and not contain malicious code. The hashing problem caused by KB2918614 is bypassed for apps that have an entry here. To do this, create registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer\SecureRepairWhitelist`, and for each trusted app, create a string value underneath with the product ID of that app.

[image: Registry screen-dump]

One way of finding this is to look in the `C:\Windows\Installer` folder during installation, and copy the GUID from the `SourceHash{xxxxGUIDxxxx}` file.

[image: Windows Installer folder in Explorer]

4. Retry the installation following the whitelisting - as the Visual Studio 2013 shell program is released by Microsoft, thus it ought to be signed.

---

**Powershell script to get list of recently created Installation GUIDs**

The following command can be run from a Powershell console in the Windows Installer directory to get a list of the installation GUIDs that were recently created by a program being installed. If the program being installed fails, run this command, and add each of the GUIDs listed in the output to the registry using the steps described above.

```
PS C:\Windows\Installer> Get-ChildItem -Filter *Hash* | ? {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime


    Directory: C:\Windows\Installer


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        2016-10-06  10:11 AM      20480 SourceHash{C8511A82-E9FD-4B6D-B1B2-378589D2B48A}
-a---        2016-10-06  11:04 AM      20480 SourceHash{D45C3EC4-282E-4798-98C7-E7BF2362F04E}
```

---

The following answer may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276554/3063884

Comment: You can find the ID to whitelist by going to c:\users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp, find the log for the installation (i.e. Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Setup_20151104_153412004-MSI_netfx_Full_x64.msi.txt), and look for the entries that look like this:

MSI (s) (58:04) [15:39:20:238]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {94A631D5-B30A-3DD8-B65C-1117C09DA73E}

Should be right above:  MSI (s) (58:04) [15:39:20:238]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3e5C36544B8 Action start 15:39:20: RegisterProduct.

Comment: @user2920518 That works. I just added a Powershell command that also lists out the GUIDs (it gets them from the Windows Installer directory)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall these 3 updates: KB2918614, KB3000988, KB3008627

Comment: Why these three? What did they do? Can they be reapplied afterwards?

Comment: @ChrisF I had the same issue with VS, so I did research on this topic and found out that these three updates somehow affects windows cryptography which is needed to calculate chechsum in order to install msi packages. So I've removed them and successfully installed VS 2013. You can reapply them later, it won't harm installed VS

Comment: Just 3 of them didn't helped. I had to remove all 2015 04 - 05 updates

Answer (score 0):

At last! I managed to fix this problem by removing all 2015 04-05 month updates (Security, Windows, Hot-fixes), now I can install MS Visual Studio 2013 and also Autodesk 3D max. I also turned off windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323808/2780791), a much easier workaround is to rename the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18` before doing the installation. It forces Windows to regenerate those files and let Windows Installer do its work.

In my particular case, I managed to install `.NET Framework 4.6.1.` However, after restarting the computer, the error reappeared when trying to install `SQL Server Express 2014`. It seems that this rename operation must be performed before each installation involving Windows Installer, if a restart has occurred in the mean time.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I still have to go through the steps in my answer (adding the SourceHash files) for some installs, especially for those from Microsoft. I tried this, and it re-created the `S-1-5-18` folder again with the same file inside, but the install I was attempting still failed... (I wish it did work, it'd be a lot faster than what I'm currently doing)