# .NET 4 fails to install because SECUREREPAIR fails to CreateContentHash of file SetupResources.dll: for computing hash Error: 997

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I have trouble installing any .NET Framework on my Windows 7 x64 machine, I keep getting the following logfile, what might cause this?

```
OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1
CommandLine = C:\09b8fe547577883fe82c\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64
TimeZone = Mitteleuropäische Zeit
Initial LCID = 1031
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup
Package Version = 4.0.30319
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Number of applicable items: 11
Exe (C:\09b8fe547577883fe82c\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
Exe (C:\09b8fe547577883fe82c\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu) failed with 0x240006 - (null).
Exe (C:\09b8fe547577883fe82c\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
MSI (C:\09b8fe547577883fe82c\netfx_Core_x64.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_20150116_161918591-MSI_netfx_Core_x64.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Schwerwiegender Fehler bei der Installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:11).
```

I have pasted a LOGfile from the MSI file, can you please take a look?

**https://paste.ee/p/zXSWH**

The main problem seems to be the following information I found in the setup log (**see line 2981 to 2999 in the log above**):

```
MSI (s) (78!78) [16:11:30:749]: SECUREREPAIR: Failed to CreateContentHash of the file: 1033\SetupResources.dll: for computing its hash. Error: 997
MSI (s) (78!78) [16:11:30:750]: SECREPAIR: Failed to create hash for the install source files
MSI (s) (78!78) [16:11:30:750]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3e5F7CE34B8
Aktion gestartet um 16:11:30: CA_NgenUpdateHighestVersion_I_RB_amd64.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8.
MSI (s) (78!78) [16:11:30:753]:
```

The only information I found concerning problems with Secrepair is KB2918614, which I completely uninstalled, rebooted, but the problem persists.
Furthermore, I have reinstalled KB2918614, applied its Hotfix (KB3000988), and the problem still persits.

It happens with .NET Framework 4.0 and 4.5, no matter which of these I try to install.

I first noticed this problem when trying to apply the update for .NET 4.5.2, which failed, so I uninstalled .NET framework 4 and 4.5 completely, and am now unable to install any of these.

Do you have any ideas what might be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: I have similar problems, the log says `MSI (s) (EC:E4) [12:21:30:914]: SOURCEDIR ==> C:\23d8e0525b22ce652a889c3f\
MSI (s) (EC:E4) [12:21:30:914]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {26784146-6E05-3FF9-9335-786C7C0FB5BE}
MSI (s) (EC:E4) [12:21:30:914]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3e5F5BB34B8
Action start 12:21:30: RegisterProduct.
MSI (s) (EC:E4) [12:21:31:064]: 
Error 997. Error 997. Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.` I thought it would be AntiVir, but uninstalling it did not change anything.

Comment: I am currently suffering from exactly the same problem, the only thing that helped for me was whitelisting the .NET upgrade package in the registry (Google for "SecureRepairPolicy"), but whenever I try to install the .NET 4.5.2 update normally it fails with te same SECUREREPAIR error. I guess Microsoft did not really fix these issues completely, because it happens no matter if KB2918614 is installed or not, or if the hotfix for that KB is installed. Seems to be independent from that update, or uninstalling leaves some remainings. Really disappointing what I experience here, I totally do blame

Answer (score 20):

The solution provided by [Thaoden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3129340/thaoden) (uninstalling KB2918614, KB3000988 and KB3008627) didn't work for me. I got the same errors after uninstalling these updates.

What did work for me was the whitelisting workaround suggested by JohnL999 [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/984b5178-d760-44e7-bb7b-046bbf74797d/net-framework-fails-to-install-applies-to-40-45-and-all-updates?forum=netfxsetup).

So, what I had to do to make it install:

1. Create a DWORD named `SecureRepairPolicy` with value `2` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`
2. Create Key `SecureRepairWhitelist` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`
3. In `SecureRepairWhitelist`, create a String with the product ID you want to whitelist as name. In my case this was `{3911CF56-9EF2-39BA-846A-C27BD3CD0685}`. You can find out the product ID in the msi log file, some lines before the error

   ```
   SECUREREPAIR: Failed to CreateContentHash of the file: 1030\SetupResources.dll: for computing its hash. Error: 997.
   ```

   It looks like this:

   ```
   SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\windows\Installer\SourceHash{3911CF56-9EF2-39BA-846A-C27BD3CD0685}
   ```

   or this:

   ```
   SOURCEDIR product ==> {3911CF56-9EF2-39BA-846A-C27BD3CD0685}
   ```

   Might be a different product ID depending on the MSI you want to install.

Comment: Thanks Torben, this is awesomeness incarnate! Your answer allowed me to install .NET 4.6 after 2 days of mucking around. The KB uninstall solution above had not worked for me. I had Visual Studio 2015 Preview, and uninstalled that, which caused the original issues.

Comment: This helped me as well.  If unable to attain the product ID (GUID) for the package that won't install, you can temporarily set the SecureRepairPolicy to a value of 1.

Comment: @ironsam I had to create the Install key but adding the DWord of SecureRepairPolicy=1 worked for me as well, on a 4.6 framework install that was failing. :)

Comment: Note: the above steps are also detailed in the [Microsoft page on KB2918614](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918614).

Comment: The same problem happened for me when installing .NET 4.7. While for installing 4.5.2 I used the suggestion from Thaoden (and it worked), I could no longer find the mentioned KB updates any more to uninstall before installing 4.7, so tried this answer and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

After some long days of fruitlessly searching, I stumbled across https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/Install-of-Sytem-update-fails-with-MSI-installer-Error-997/td-p/1802731. It says there to uninstall KB2918614, KB3000988 and KB3008627. That did the trick for me.
Apparently, the culprit is KB3008627 as I didn't uninstall that one in my previous attempts.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me on Windows 7 x64 SP1. I first only uninstalled KB3008627, but I got the same result. Uninstalling KB3008627 hung my computer at "Preparing to configure windows... Do not turn off your computer" for more than 30 minutes, so I had to hard reset and then wait for about 10 minutes until it finished. I then uninstalled KB3000988 which didn't require a reboot, tried again, but I got the same result. Finally, after uninstalling KB2918614 and rebooting as requested, the .net 4.5.2 update finished successfully! :)

Comment: I can confirm that uninstalling KB3008627 (in addition to uninstalling KB2918614 and KB3000988) does actually help. Previously, I only uninstalled the two in brackets, because that's what you find anywhere on the web, but obviously, KB3008627 plays an important role in this weird scenario as well. Does anybdoy know if uninstalling these three makes my computer more vulnerable to attacks?
I totally wish that Microsoft tested these scenarios more thoroughly however... :(

Comment: After uninstalling the KBs and successfully installing .NET 4.5.2, I ran Windows Update which reinstalled two KBs (2918614 and 3008627 I think). So I think I closed all vulnerabilities that I can close atm.

Answer (score 5):

I still kept getting this error even after uninstalling KB2918614, etc., and what finally fixed it for me was to rename `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18` to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18.bak` for example. Only then when retrying the failing installation will it succeed! :)

The failing installation will recreate that folder.

I found this solution in the comments section of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-i-o-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service.aspx) blog post:

> Gerd Hübner 4 Sep 2015 6:15 AM #
>
> In short: Rename the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far (easiest to do). However, it must be done before each installation involving Windows Installer, if a restart has occurred. E.g. It worked when installing .NET Fwk, but it happened again after restarting and trying to install SQL Express 2014. Thanks.

Comment: it works for me...thanks