# InstallShield - Offline join completion information was not found

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I'm trying to add an installation project using InstallShield to my WPF application. I added the project, went through the wizard and added the primary output of my project, leaving most of the other default settings. I can build the installation, and looking at the logs, it seems to be adding all the required assemblies. When I attempt to install, however, the wizard comes up and I click through until the installation begins and I get the following message:

> Error 2709. Offline join completion information was not found.

Does anyone have a solution for this or a way to track down the root cause? I'm new to InstallShield so any tips would be appreciated. The only thing I could find with a google search was to remove a couple of windows updates. This did not work for me.

Comment: There's another post that might help [NET 4 fails to install because SECUREREPAIR fails to CreateContentHash of file SetupResources.dll: for computing hash Error: 997][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019083/net-4-fails-to-install-because-securerepair-fails-to-createcontenthash-of-file

Comment: the registry hack did fix it for me.