# Error while installing sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows

i am trying to install sql server 2014 on my laptop(windows 7).While installing the software i am getting an error saying
" Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation in progress"

If i click OK and the process starts and again the same error.
Could any one help me out.
Thanks..

Comment: http://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Install-Failure-Error-997-Overlapped-I-O-operation-is-in-progress.html---

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295712

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 4 fails to install because SECUREREPAIR fails to CreateContentHash of file SetupResources.dll: for computing hash Error: 997](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019083/net-4-fails-to-install-because-securerepair-fails-to-createcontenthash-of-file)

Answer (score 2):

The error "Overlapped I/O operation in progress" can be caused by wrong permissions of folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18. User SYSTEM must have full control permission to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Great rebuttal above

For anyone else stuggling with this on W10, delete or rename this folder:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18

It gets recreated during the SQL 2012 / 2014 install

Answer (score -1):

This was found by googling your error message. Next time google before asking here.

Link: http://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Install-Failure-Error-997-Overlapped-I-O-operation-is-in-progress.html

```
Causes:
This error is caused by Microsoft security updates.
Solution:
Remove the updates
Go to Control Panel > Uninstall a program (or Programs and Features).
In the left menu, click View installed updates.
In the search box at the top-right search for KB2918614. If you find it, uninstall it.
Do another search for KB3000988. If you find it, uninstall it.
Reboot the computer and try installing the Autodesk software again.
```

Comment: I've spent hours googling the error message and trying different fixes and solutions. But none of them worked. Your answer did not help me too. Question is about SQL server but you posted link to Autodesk software. Your advice "Next time google before asking here" is useless.