# MSI minor upgrade fails with UAC due to SECREPAIR hash compare failing

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

I'm having some trouble with a Microsoft Windows Installer Setup (created using WIX 3.10.2).

I Installed the base version of the application. So far so good.
Then, I wanted to a apply a "Minor Upgrade" and that should work without elevation as the package is digitally signed etc.

However, I get a UAC prompt at the installation step "Registering product" when trying to install this minor upgrade. It seems as some "SECREPAIR" component of MSI is comparing some hash values and determines that something is not right, whereby I get a LUA request row to supply admin rights. I can't find any relevant information for this specific "SECREAPIR" error or error code.

Below is a relevant excerpt from the MSI Log created using /L*V command-line arguments when launching the minor upgrade setup msi file.

Also, I can confirm that this error occurs both on Windows 10 (Fall Creator's update) and (Windows 7 SP1 x64).

As a final note:
I am aware of the similar issue created by Microsoft when they released a faulty security patch (https://www.infoworld.com/article/2608940/microsoft-windows/microsoft-patch-kb-2918614-triggers--key-not-valid-for-use---more-errors.html), but the error message is not the same, even though it also involved "SECREPAIR" component of MSI.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks!

```
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Doing action: RegisterProduct
Action 13:18:55: RegisterProduct. Registering product
Action start 13:18:55: RegisterProduct.
RegisterProduct: Registering product
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Re-registering product - performing upgrade of existing installation.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is '\\server\xxxx\Setup\'.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is '\\server\xxxx\Setup\'.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{D0996A82-ED26-4469-B92E-5B8958C3568F}'.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: SOURCEDIR ==> \\server\xxxx\Setup\
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {D0996A82-ED26-4469-B92E-5B8958C3568F}
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Source type from package 'MySetup.msi': 10
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:017]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:55:033]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\Windows\Installer\SourceHash{D0996A82-ED26-4469-B92E-5B8958C3568F}
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:57:705]: SECREPAIR: filename: MySetup.msi Stored Hash Value:EP6Iaaqorv2W1VLclxB9LNP2oyfeCzXPYwF8HvdGGdQ= Current Hash:PFPnvCaXVF5QB3eMzwlyKBagathyNdr+VfuXA2hWj2Q=
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:57:705]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:18:57:705]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:19:05:636]: MSI_LUA: Credential Request return = 0x800704C7
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:19:05:636]: Note: 1: 3 
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:19:05:636]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3329EF5F0
Action ended 13:19:05: RegisterProduct. Return value 2.
MSI (s) (F0:34) [13:19:05:668]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019083/net-4-fails-to-install-because-securerepair-fails-to-createcontenthash-of-file    ??

Comment: @PhilDW Unfortunately, no. In that post, the error is different. In my case it does compute the hash value it seems but it compares old with new value and they differ. Probably that is why it is throwing a UAC. But I do not understand why it is doing the SECUREREPAIR step at all.