# Make changes to registry before installation of a program

Tags: c#, registry, installshield, registrykey

Ok, I created an installation file for my program with InstallShield(software). I was not able to successfully install the program until I made changes to the registry as described here **[.NET 4 fails to install because SECUREREPAIR fails to CreateContentHash of file SetupResources.dll: for computing hash Error: 997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019083/net-4-fails-to-install-because-securerepair-fails-to-createcontenthash-of-file)**. After making the changes to the registry, I am able to install my program. So, the registry changes are to be made before running my installer file. Can I not embed that **.reg** file somewhere from the InstallShield while creating the installer file so that the **.reg** file runs before my actual installation begins?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action in a script to update the registry and add to the sequence. Below is a rough example (won't work off without some tweaking).

Then add to your sequence before ISInstallPrerquisites in the UI Sequence.

> STRING svCmd;
>   STRING svCmdPath;
>   begin
>
> 'For DWORD:
>
> svCmd = "reg add " + KeyName + " /v " + ValueName + " /t REG_DWORD /d " + dataValue + " /f";
>
> 'For String:
>
> svCmd = "reg add " + KeyName + " /v " + ValueName + " /t REG_SZ /d " + dataValue + " /f";
>
> svCmdPath = "cmd";
>
> ```
>   LaunchAppAndWait(svCmdPath, "/c \"" + svCmd +"\"", LAAW_OPTION_HIDDEN | LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> - Does this problem occur on all computers, or just some? What OS?
> - What is your anti-virus softare, security suite?
> - Are you on a locked-down corporate SOE? (Standard Operating Environment).
>
>   - Are there custom policies?
>   - Are you using mandatory (or temporary) profiles?

---

***Pre-Requisite***: If this is the official **Microsoft .NET 4 runtime installer** which falls over, then I would exclude it from my own setup and deliver it as a pre-requisite alongside my main installer, or I would simply point to the web-page to download the latest version of that runtime. I much prefer the latter option since what you deliver with your package could be outdated in no time as new security hotfixes become available. ***Crucially***: most people will probably have this runtime installed by now?

***Windows Update***: I might even tell the user to install via Windows Update, but that is more of a manual process with more steps. *Isn't .NET 4 a mandatory Windows Update install by now?*

***Corporate Users***: Corporate packagers will appreciate the separation of runtimes from your own package seeing as much time is spent taking pre-requisite packages out of vendor packages. They simply need some one-page documentation telling them what runtime is needed. *They will have the right one pre-packaged according to their own corporate standard - and debugged of issues like you mention*. There is not much need to combat the runtime setup.

***Real World***: You can deliver a **`*.reg`** file along with your **.NET 4 installer** file with a brief **`README.txt`** describing the problem you mention. Then they can deal with it if they have to, and if the problem is not seen then you avoid all the fuss. Then you add a **LaunchCondition** to your main setup to prevent its installation unless **.NET 4** is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installer softwares usually (always ? Well instalShield has one at least) have a "Registry" feature where you can define the registry hierarchy/entries/values you wanna add.

No need of any script or reg file. All values are set up before the installation they are linked with.

Anyway, you are unlikely asked to find a work around as InstallShield already deal with it for you. Just set it up in the installer.