# Android Studio - Error 997 "overlapped IO operation is in progress" during VC++ Redistributable installation

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-installer

While installing Android Studio, I always get the following error message `Error 997 "overlapped IO operation is in progress"` in the log. This is during the step where the Microsoft VC++ Redistributable installation takes place.

Here is the log file:

```
OS Version Information: 
         OS Version = 6.2.9200, Platform 2
         OS Description = Future OS - x64 Enterprise Edition 
        OS Version Information 
         Environment details: 
         CommandLine = d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\Setup.exe /passive /norestart /showfinalerror
        Environment details 
         Entering Function: LocalizedData::CreateLocalizedData
        succeeded
         Entering Function: EngineData::CreateEngineData
         Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
        succeeded
         MaintenanceMode determination: evaluating EnterMaintenanceModeIf
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         MaintenanceMode determination evaluates to 'not in maintenance mode'
         Operation Type: 
         Operation: Installing
        Operation Type 
         Package details: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable Setup
         Package Name = Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable Setup
         Package Version = 10.0.40219
        Package details 
         User Experience Data Collection Policy: 
         User Experience Data Collection Policy: UserControlled
        User Experience Data Collection Policy 
         Entering Function: UiDataT::CreateUiDataT
        succeeded
         Global Block Checks: Checking for global blockers
         BlockIf: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable is not supported on this operating system.
         And: evaluating
         Equals: evaluating
        Equals evaluated to true
         GreaterThan: evaluating
        GreaterThan evaluated to false
         And evaluated to false
         BlockIf evaluated to false
         BlockIf: A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.
         And: evaluating
         Equals: evaluating
        Equals evaluated to true
         LessThan: evaluating
        LessThan evaluated to false
         And evaluated to false
         BlockIf evaluated to false
         Global Block Checks no blocking conditions found
         Applicability for Installing: evaluating each item
         Determining state: of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.cab
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Determining state of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.cab - available but not verified yet
         Determining state: of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Determining state of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp - available but not verified yet
         Determining state: of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Determining state of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi - available but not verified yet
         Determining state: of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Determining state of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi - authored action for this item is NoOp
         Determining state: of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Determining state of d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp - not applicable 
         Determining state: of MSIServer
        Determining state of MSIServer - payload not required for this item to perform action.
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Applicability for Installing determination is complete
         Applicability Result Count: 
         Number of applicable items: 3
        Applicability Result Count 
         Action: System Requirement Checks
         Action: Disk space check for items being downloaded
        Action complete
         Action: Enumerating incompatible processes
        Action complete
         Action: Enumerating incompatible services
        Action complete
         Action complete
         Action: Downloading and/or Verifying Items
         d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.cab: Verifying signature for vc_red.cab
        d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.cab Signature verified successfully for vc_red.cab
         d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi: Verifying signature for vc_red.msi
        d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi Signature verified successfully for vc_red.msi
         d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp: Verifying signature for msp_kb2565063.msp
        d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\msp_kb2565063.msp Signature verified successfully for msp_kb2565063.msp
        Action complete
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Exists: evaluating
        Exists evaluated to false
         Action: Performing actions on all Items
         Action: Performing Action on MSI at d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi
          Returning IDOK. INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR [Error 997.Overlapped I/O operation is in progress. ]
         MSI (d:\68972a9195f7b9c35b\vc_red.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable Setup_20150205_155712703-MSI_vc_red.msi.txt
         PerformOperation returned 1603 (translates to HRESULT = 0x80070643)
        Action complete
         OnFailureBehavior for this item is to Rollback.
         Action: Performing actions on all Items
        Action complete
         Action complete
         Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:04).
```

It's coming when the installer runs the installation of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable Setup".

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you run Windows Update, do you get problems applying updates? There was a known issue with KB2918614 - more information here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2918614

Comment: I have installed Windows updates.but still Android Studio could not installed.its showing above screens..

Comment: I know you got it working, but if you need to get the original account working, and it is related to the MS update KB218614, then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28950288/3063884

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened when installing `.NET Framework 4.6.1` and the easiest solution (after 1 day of trial and error) was to rename the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18` before starting the installation. The same error happened for SQL Server Express 2014 installation and the same trick worked for it.

Credits go to [Rami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323808/2780791), for pointing out this simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i created new Windows user account and installed Android Studio.Then its installed successfully.I don't know why,but its worked for me.